# React - redux form - unable to type after mapping value property

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux-form, the value of the text box is not getting update on typing, i.e I am unable to type in the input box.

**Note**: Redux-dev tool is logging event on typing buttons, but text-box content isn't updating

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class ExamSettingForm extends React.Component {

  renderInput = ({input}) => {
    console.log(input);
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange = {input.onChange}
        value = {input.value}/>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form>
        <Field
          name="description"
          component={this.renderInput}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'editExamSetForm'
})(ExamSettingForm);
```

As soon the input is updated with the "**value**" property, I am unable to type anything in the input box. I've tried the syntax

```
<input {...input}/>
```

Comment: [Your code works](https://codesandbox.io/s/jl8klll359). There might be something else wrong in another part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are destructuring `input` from `props` in your `renderInput` method. When you used `<input {...input}/>` what was the `input` there? It should be the entire `props` object:

```
class ExamSettingForm extends React.Component {
  renderInput = (props) => {
    return (
      <input {...props} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form>
        <Field
          name="description"
          component={this.renderInput}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```